# How to automatically get hotkey on a WPF tooltip?

Tags: wpf

In my window, I have this:

```
<UIElement.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Gesture="Ctrl+Left" Command="{Binding MoveTaskCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Static plugin:MoveDirection.Left}"/>
    ...
```

And down in the tree, I have this:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    ToolTip="Promote to Parent Level (Ctrl+Left)" Command="{Binding MoveTaskCommand}"
    CommandParameter="{x:Static plugin:MoveDirection.Left}">
    ...
```

I don't like the redundancy, and I don't like copy pasting my hotkey's "Ctrl+Left" into the tooltip. I'm 99% certain WPF has a better way of doing it than this.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

> Could someone point me in the right direction?

**Option 1**: I would try using a [custom Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903943%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) maybe "IsToolTipGesture".  In the PropertyChangedCallback, check if there's a [ToolTip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tooltip.aspx) and any [UIElement.InputBindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.inputbindings.aspx).  If there are, update the ToolTip with the appropriate information from the InputBindings.

**Option 2**: Another thing to try if you want this behavior on ALL elements below a certain root is using a similar approach with an attached property and recursively checking child elements (via [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx)) to see if they have a ToolTip and any InputBindings.

Comment: let me know how this goes... it sounds quite interesting, indeed.